# Getting error "??? 33711616 104857600 104857600 ???" while installing Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I have an Acer Nitro 5 and I am trying to dual boot Ubuntu 20.04.1 alongside Windows 10.

When I reached the "choose installation type" step, I chose "something else" since I had a free space of 174 GB on my hard disk which I had left for Ubuntu. But when I created a partition with mount point `/`, I am receiving the following error and whenever I dismiss it it pops again.

[image: error]

How can I correct it?

Comment: Ubuntu can't be installed on a NTFS partition. And unallocated space is not a partition. You are doing something wrong.

Comment: I tried creating the partition in free space(178258MB) not /dev/sda4

Comment: Use gparted to create a partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why or how it happened but i shut down the installation midway forcefully and tried installing ubuntu again. I followed the exact same steps I did the last time (even while partitioning) and this time it worked perfectly.